# Caching data using xml

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I'm presently on a e-learning project using the custom php (not any framework or cms).For content of one page of my project i have to fetch about 1000 data from database,presently i'm using pagination on that page and displaying 100s of data every page.Now i'm thinking if i fetch all data from the database at a time and store it in xml and when user sweep between the pages of pagination the data will be fetched from the xml rather than database it may be good in the sense that it will reduce the database hits.But i have confusion that is the xml pursing may effect on my project execution time?If any better better idea please share with me.
My project's environment is like below
php 5
Mysql
Jquery

Answer (score 1):

This still sounds inefficient since you have to still parse the xml.

I believe the most efficient way to do it (optimised for page views) would be to pre-generate the html of your lists.

That means everytime the database changes, you re-create the html, but only once.
Then all you do is simply serve that html from your web-server without any script executing.

Comment: I understand what you are saying still i have one question fetching 100 data from database or fetching 100 data from xml file which one is time consuming?

Comment: That depends on several factors. I can only guess. To be sure you will need to do a benchmark.